# How can i fetch php data dynamically on the same page without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php

Please i want to update my contents every second on the same page using php and javascript. e.g i want the a span of id user to change every one second from data gotten from database.

```
   var data = `<?php echo $data; ?>`;

    setInterval(() => {
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            if(data){
                resolve(data);
            }        
        })

        promise.then(res => {

            var user = document.querySelector("#user");

            user.innerHTML = res;

        })

    }, 1000)
```

Comment: AJAX is the keyword you are looking for

Comment: ^ but also maybe look at "web sockets" just so you know what is possible.